# Google Chart: "Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I try to generate a google chart. It returns "**Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined**" in the chart area but no error in the console.

```
function drawChart(chart_data, chartType, chartOptions){

           console.log(chartOptions);

            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(chart_data);

            var chart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({

                chartType: chartType,
                dataTable: data,
                options: chartOptions,
                containerId: 'chart'

            });

            chart.draw();
        }
```

The results of the `console.log` is a string that looks like:

```
{"title":"test","vAxis":{"minValue":"0"},"hAxis":{"showTextEvery":"1"},"chartArea":{"width":"70%","height":"90%"},"pointSize":"7","height":"500","intervals":{"lineWidth":2,"barWidth":0.5,"color":"#000000"}}
```

If I use (copy-paste) the result of the `console.log` instead of using `chartOptions` as `options`, the chart is displayed perfectly.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Is `chartOptions` a string?  If so you may need to do `chartOptions = JSON.parse(chartOptions);` before you use it for the chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only explanation I can think of (given that copy-pasting it works fine), is that in one instance you are sending a string, and when you copy paste it back in, you then have an object.

[image]

So if you look at the console log, it SHOULD look like the first one in the picture above.  If it looks like the second, you need to do

```
chartOptions = JSON.parse(chartOptions);

var chart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
              chartType: chartType,
              dataTable: data,
              options: chartOptions,
              containerId: 'chart'
            });
```